# Chain Pull LIght

Tags: electrical

I have a chain pull light fixture that also feeds two outlets.  How can I add a switch to the light without shutting off the outlets when the light is off.

Comment: I don't think you can. You'd have to separate the light fixture from the 2 outlets

Comment: Are the outlets downstream from the light, or just on the same circuit?

Comment: @jeffcates my guess is he's talking about something like this: https://i.imgur.com/5UsfIoe.jpg

Comment: If so, then no way to sepersate them. But he says 2 outets, are they 2 or 2 sets? Singe deplex (2) or 2 duplex sets (4). More info and a drawing!

Comment: I went to hook up the wire from the switch to the light and saw two other wires that went into the box also and they led to the wall and I believe they belong to two plugs.

Comment: I have two ceramic pull-chain light fixtures (std screw base) which each has a receptacle (single) in the base. The pull chain switch does not switch the receptacle, but only the light. The receptacle is always on.

Comment: LED motion-sensing bulbs make convenient replacements in pull-chain lamp sockets. They're available for US$3 in some locations (subsidized by local electric companies). No wiring., and they never get left on accidentally.

Comment: Yes, the fixture looks like the picture.  Simple pull chain light and the outlets are fed directly from the light.  two wires connected to the light and incoming wires

Comment: Thank you.  Motion sensing socket seems to be the simplest answer.  Thank you all.  Not sure if I am replying correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done easily by pigtailing wires inside the junction box under the light; one part is 'unswitched', wires coming from the source go into the box and split into two sub-branches; one goes through the box and continue on to the plugs, while the other half splits to branch off to the new wall switch, a "switch loop", and then back up to power the light.

Comment: Are you able to make a sketch for me

Comment: I wouldn't know how to post a sketch, but I can try describing the circuit in detail, if you'd like.

Comment: The branch circuit supplying power to the light should be split into two directions; one branch going to poer the new light switch and the other branch going directly to the plugs. Watch out for box fill though. You may need to add an extension box onto the existing ceiling junction box to make enough room for the extra wires and wire nuts (marrettes).

Comment: I do not understand the jargon.  I purchased Romex 14 with white, black and ground wires.  Please describe as white, black and ground from the circuit box to the light fixture and plug wires.

Comment: And also to the switch.

Comment: The power comes into your ceiling box on a Black wire, and goes out on a white wire. The bare copper wire is the Grounding or